# How do I use shell commands in Code::blocks c++?

Tags: c++, shell, command-line, terminal, codeblocks

I have a project in which I have to use the linux shell commands "wc" and "date" in a c++ program. I'm using the code::blocks IDE to make my .cpp file but I don't know how to use those commands within the compiler. Any tips?

Comment: Do you need to use them as part of the build process or just in code?

Comment: @VTT I need to use them within the code, the "wc" function to read the amount of letters, words and bits in a textfile and the "date" function to get a specified unix epoch time format.  These commands need to be executed within the program execution, not before